# Good place to keep learning Openshift?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I'm currently using the free training that Red Had offers to learn Openshift as developer and Admin. Do you know any other place I can use to gain "to prod" experience?
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The free training offered by Red Hat is a good start. You probably also already discovered the following two resources that can be recommend:

- https://learn.openshift.com
- https://try.openshift.com

Since OpenShift is Kubernetes, most of the Kubernetes resources also apply, my personal favourites include:

- https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way
- https://github.com/jamiehannaford/what-happens-when-k8s

So books like "Kubernetes in Action" or "Kubernetes: Up and Running" also show you the core concepts.

Comment: https://developers.redhat.com/products/openshift/getting-started and https://developers.redhat.com/topics/kubernetes/ have some good resources as well

Comment: That's great! I'm currently getting hands on https://learn.openshift.com